# Unable to find element after clicking submit button

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have an issue with the loading of web page after the whole form is filled neatly.
The next page is where i need to do data extraction.
This is the website:
https://enquiry.icegate.gov.in/enquiryatices/sbTrack

Please find sample data here :

```
SELECT LOCATION : HYDERABAD ICD (INSNF6)
 
ENTER SHIPPING BILL No. :  8991212

ENTER SHIPPING BILL DATE :  29-09-2017

ENTER IMAGE LETTERS : This is the Captcha( to be entered manually)
```

The issue is as soon as the submit button is clicked, the next page doesn't load and thus below lines are trying to find an element which didn't load at all.
My friend have tried it with java and it seems to work with (.Refresh) but in VBA , that's a problem.

**Please someone help me out here.**

```
Option Explicit
Sub icegateNewww()
Dim e, bot As WebDriver, ele As SelectElement, eledpTD As Object, r As Long, i As Long
Dim elem  As WebElement
Set bot = New WebDriver
r = 1

With bot
.Start "Chrome"
While (Len(Range("A" & r)) > 0)

          .Get "https://enquiry.icegate.gov.in/enquiryatices/sbTrack"
'line:
        .FindElementByXPath("//select[@id='location']").SendKeys Range("A" & r)
        .FindElementByXPath("//input[@id='sbNO']").SendKeys Range("B" & r)
        .FindElementByXPath("//img[@src='/enquiryatices/image/Dateicon.gif']").Click            'To open date picker
                    
        'To pick up the date
        
        Set ele = .FindElementByName("calendar-month").AsSelect
        ele.SelectByIndex Month(Cells(r, 3)) - 1
        Set ele = .FindElementByName("calendar-year").AsSelect
        ele.SelectByValue CStr(Year(Cells(r, 3)))
        Set eledpTD = .FindElementsByClass("dpTD")
        For Each e In eledpTD
            If Val(e.Text) = Val(Day(Cells(r, 3))) Then
                e.Click: Exit For
            End If
        Next e
               
      .FindElementById("captchaResp").Click
      .Wait 10000
      .FindElementByXPath("//input[@id='SubB']").Click               'To click on the submit button
     
'If (.FindElementByXPath("//span[contains(text(),'Invalid Code! Please try again!')]") = "Invalid Code! Please try again!") Then
'End If
   
'GoTo line

       .Wait (3000)
         
                                
      'Below lines are to click on each element & extract the data
      
      .FindElementByXPath("//span[contains(text(),'SB Details')]").Click
      Range("D" & r) = .FindElementByXPath("//div[@id='sbICES_Details']//center//div//table").Text
      
      
      .FindElementByXPath("//span[contains(text(),'Item Wise Reward Details')]").Click
      Range("E" & r) = .FindElementByXPath("//div[@id='itemWiseRewardTdId']//center//div//table").Text
      
r = r + 1
Wend
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Separate out captcha into a new post and keep this one about the one issue. What happens with the attempt to submit and what is the minimal code to reproduce that problem?

Comment: @QHarr I have edited this question, because the most annoying part is the "Page loading issue"  after the submit button is hit.
The page seems to not load at all, and if i run that without the code on a normal window, i need to refresh the page and it loads up all the data, but if i keep a (.Refresh)  line of code, then the whole code falls apart.